# Splash screen distorted on Samsung Galaxy S10

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have generated the splash screens for an app using the following site. See image of screens below.
https://apetools.webprofusion.com/#/tools/imagegorilla

However I am getting reports that a Samsung Galaxy S10 user is seeing a distorted splash screen.
The resolution for this device appears to be 2,280 x 1,080 which is quite long compared to the ratios of the images I have generated.

port-xhdpi is 720x1280

port-xxhdpi is 960x1600

port-xxxhdpi is 1280x1920

Any idea how to resolve this? Do I need to generate a different splash screen with a new image size?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I run across the same issue in my Ionic with Capacitor app.

I was able to resolve the problem, adding this line in the capacitor.config.json file:

```
  "plugins": {
    "SplashScreen": {
      "androidScaleType": "CENTER_CROP",
    }
  }
```

as stated here:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/splash-screen-is-stretched-in-some-devices/185430/8